# TranslateZ leads to a different result on Safari compared to Chrome

Tags: css, 3d

Despite the usage of a '-webkit-transform', and 'perspective:800px' on the parent, my div.container with a 'translateZ' is in a good position on Chrome but is 100px closer to me on Safari.

Do you have any idea about what could the problem be?

```css
#bigContainer .container{
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(110px) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg) scale(0.3);
  transform: translateZ(110px) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg) scale(0.3);
 }
```

```html
  <div id="bigContainer"> 
        <div class="container">
          <div id="shape-1"> 
            <div class="element-1"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Thanks, 
Eric